# Firework Show - A study on pyrotechnics

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image]

(Author Note) A while ago I made some puzzles for a now defunct puzzle hunt project, here's one of them. The answer to this ([and most other puzzles of said hunt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22A+study+on%22+is%3Aquestion)) is a single word. The puzzle itself is fully contained within the image above. Author notes don't matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word is

> FORTITUDE

If you

> isolate the red, green, and blue components of the segmented displays they give F, O, R from the first one, T, I, T from the second, and U, D, E from the third.
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

Comment: Congrats! Hope you enjoyed the puzzle!

Comment: @Auribouros Thank you, I liked it. Looking forward to more and still working on the clock one...